# DataFrameGroupby.agg NamedAgg on same column errors out on custom function, but works on bult-in function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Setup

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(zip([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 7, 7, 9, 10],
                      *np.random.randint(1, 100, 20).reshape(-1,10)),
                  columns=['A','B', 'C'])

Out[127]:
    A   B   C
0   1  45  71
1   1  48  89
2   2  65  89
3   2  68  13
4   2  68  59
5   3  10  66
6   7  84  40
7   7  22  88
8   9  37  47
9  10  88  89

f = lambda x: x.max()
```

NamedAgg on built-in function works fine

```
df.groupby('A').agg(B_min=('B', 'min'), B_max=('B', 'max'), C_max=('C', 'max'))

Out[133]:
    B_min  B_max  C_max
A
1      45     48     89
2      65     68     89
3      10     10     66
7      22     84     88
9      37     37     47
10     88     88     89
```

NamedAgg on custom function `f` errors out

```
df.groupby('A').agg(B_min=('B', 'min'), B_max=('B', f), C_max=('C', 'max'))

KeyError: "[('B', '<lambda>')] not in index"
```

Is there any explanation for this error? is this error an intentional restriction?

Comment: likely a bug. Runs fine with `.agg(B_max=('B',f))`.

Comment: @QuangHoang: yeah, I tested on `.agg(B_max=('B',f))`. SeriesGroupby also runs fine `df.groupby('A').B.agg(B_min='min', B_max=f)`

Comment: @ALollz: wow... it is truly surprising!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of [`_mangle_lambda_list`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.3/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py#L1758-L1788), which gets called at some point. There seems to be a mismatch where the resulting aggregation gets renamed but the list of output columns, `ordered` which are then used [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.3/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py#L263-L265), doesn't get changed. Since that function specifically checks for `if com.get_callable_name(aggfunc) == "<lambda>"` any name other than `'<lambda>'` will work without issue:

#### Sample data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(zip([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 7, 7, 9, 10],
                      *np.random.randint(1, 100, 20).reshape(-1,10)),
                  columns=['A','B', 'C'])
f = lambda x: x.max()
kwargs = {'B_min': ('B', 'min'), 'B_max':('B', f), 'C_max':('C', 'max')}
```

---

Here are the most relevant major steps that get called when you aggregate, and we can see where the KeyError comes from.

```
func, columns, order = pd.core.groupby.generic._normalize_keyword_aggregation(kwargs)

print(order)
#[('B', 'min'), ('B', '<lambda>'), ('C', 'max')]

func = pd.core.groupby.generic._maybe_mangle_lambdas(func)
df.groupby('A')._aggregate(func)
#     B              C
#   min <lambda_0> max        # _0 ruins indexing with ('B', '<lambda>')
#A                    
#1   45         48  89
#2   65         68  89
#3   10         10  66
#7   22         84  88
#9   37         37  47
#10  88         88  89
```

---

Because `_mangle_lambda_list` is only called when there are multiple aggregations for the same column, you *can* get away with the `'<lambda>'` name, so long as it is **the only aggregation** for that column.

```
df.groupby('A').agg(A_min=('A', 'min'), B_max=('B', f))
#    A_min  B_max
#A               
#1       1     48
#2       2     68
#3       3     10
#7       7     84
#9       9     37
#10     10     88
```